# Is the electric force quantum?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, coulombs-law, discrete

I'm asking if the electric force is quantum, and I'm not referring to photons, which I understand is quantized.  Unless of course, the answer is that the electric force is only felt upon absorption of a photon, which then answers the question as well.

I'm wondering if there is a distance from a charged particle where the strength of the field would fall below the quantized amount and so effectively become zero.

Comment: The classical fields are averages of many quantized energy exchanges. The mental model of "the field of a quantum" is therefor approaching the question from the wrong perspective. A quantum doesn't have a field. A classical field has many quanta. The problem with "static fields" of classical charges is that they are already a poor approximation in the classical theory. To "keep a charge in place" we need a solid matter structure... which defines a preferred coordinate system and hence violates relativity. In the relativistic theory everything is necessarily  a dynamic scattering process.

Comment: Is it possible to say the electric force is conveyed with a particle or not at least?

Comment: Not if you mean the "electric force" in the sense of an electrostatic force. For one thing quanta are not material objects but energy exchanges. An electrostatic field acting on a non-moving charge distribution does classically not exchange any energy. You have to let the charges move freely so they can accelerate... then one can talk about energy and momentum transfer. We don't have to go all the way to electrodynamics to see that static forces are problematic. In Newtonian mechanics we define a force as that which accelerates a body. Even there the static case is not part of the definition.